# how to align two columns contents in same line

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

below is my code

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-input-icon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label></label>
                <label style="margin-top: 30px;">test</label>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

i have created two columns in one row
  first column has label and under that input box
  next column has only label and it should be aligned inline with input box, but since only label was there it used to display on top. So i wrote one dummy label. Still it is not aligned with input box.
  how to do this? Is there any way to do it in bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Add `&nbsp;` between `label`. There should be some content inside `label` to make it work. So just add `html` code of empty space.

```
<label>&nbsp;</label>
```

However a better approach will be without bootstrap columns and using custom css as follows:

```css
.column-holder {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.column-holder .column {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-holder">
  <div class="column">
    <label>name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-input-icon">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <label>test</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without Bootstrap :**

that is happens because you put every `label` inside same `div` tag again and again.

```
            <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label>name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-input-icon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label></label>
                  <label style="margin-top: 30px;">test</label>
            </div>
```

when you remove those two same `div` tags or put all labels and `input` tag inside a single label then all elements will gets inline automatically.

**HOW TO DO :**

```html
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-input-icon">
            
                <label></label>
                <label style="margin-top: 30px;">test</label>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

---

**Using Bootstrap :**

Yes you can do same thing using bootstrap even that is more easy and looks more beautiful. here is a simple example for you.
**copy this code and run with chrome or firefox or safari this code will work perfectly**
you can visit this site:[for more detail](http://crackit9.blogspot.in)
or check this out[inline form using bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_inline&stacked=h)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Example of inline form</h2>
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label >Name : </label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name ">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email : </label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="enter your email">
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```